# How to determine a positions of MeshView?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am using javafx.
I have a MeshView which is wall of a cube.
I try to find a way how to get it coordinates (x,y,z).
I need it to detrmine if the wall is visible on the screen or not
and if not how to rotate it to make it visible.

These methods:

```
myMeshViewWall.getLocalBounds()
myMeshViewWall.getBoundsInLocal()
myMeshViewWall.getBoundsInParent()
```

always gives me same result when I rotate my cube.
Wherever my wall is, the result is not changing.

What shoudl I do to achive my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the coordinates from the object in the scene you can try:

```
myMeshViewWall.localToScene(myMeshViewWall.getBoundsInLocal());
```

This will transform the bounds from the local coordinate space of this node into the coordinate space of its scene.